# How can I confirm whether whitespace or special characters are escaped in a wildcard pattern?

Tags: bash, shell, posix, glob, ls

I know that when you use a for loop in Bash, the items that you loop through are separated using the `$IFS` variable.

However, if I run the following commands, I correctly show the two files I have created - even though they have spaces:

```sh
touch file\ {1..2}.txt
for file in *.txt; do
    echo "Found: ${file}"
done
```

The output is:

```
Found: file 1.txt
Found: file 2.txt
```

I am *assuming* that this is because when the shell sees the wildcard pattern, it expands it and *escapes* any special characters or whitespace. This is in contrast to if I run:

```sh
touch file\ {1..2}.txt
files=$(ls *.txt)
for file in $files; do
    echo "Found: ${file}"
done
```

This results in:

```
Found: file
Found: 1.txt
Found: file
Found: 2.txt
```

Which makes sense - by default `$IFS` contains whitespace, so the file names are split.

What I want to understand is:

1. Am I correct that wildcard expansion results in a set of strings that contain *escaped* special characters
2. Where is it documented that this is the case, if I am correct?
3. Is there any way to *show* that this is happening?

I was hoping I could use something like `set -x` to show what the wildcard expands to and actually see the escaped characters, because I really want to be able to understand what is going on here.

I am writing a long series of articles on effective shell usage (effective-shell.com) and I'm struggling to find a way to explain the differences of behaviour here, I'm assuming that the shell is escaping characters but I'd like to know if this is the case and how to *see* it if possible!

Thanks in advance.
done

Comment: Consider that `for file in *.txt` works for the same reason that `ls *.txt` works. Using `ls` for programmatic purposes is discourage precisely because it forces the shell to parse file names out of raw text, rather than generating them directly from lower-level system calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Am I correct that wildcard expansion results in a set of strings that contain *escaped* special characters

No. There is no need for the shell to escape special characters at that point, because filename expansion is the last word expansion to be performed; strings resulting from it are not subjected to word splitting or any other expansion; they stay as-is. This is documented in [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html#Shell-Expansions) as follows:

> The order of expansions is: brace expansion; tilde expansion, parameter and variable expansion, arithmetic expansion, and command substitution (done in a left-to-right fashion); word splitting; and filename expansion.